# How to view (or browse) simplified pages on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, accessibility

How can I access simplified Stack Exchange pages? I was browsing, and a clickable popdown tab at the top came by, allowing the switch. However, I am unsure about how to bring it back. Simplified pages may be more suitable for browsing with a Braille Reader or with TalkBack on Android (although, I need to investigate).

Comment: If you are using Chrome on Android, I think what you saw might have been a feature of Chrome. I have seen the pop-up before. While investigating this, I found an article describing how to enable the feature: https://www.androidhire.com/how-to-enable-simplified-view-in-google-chrome/. I found that the feature was off so I re-enabled it. But that pop-up doesn't seem to pop-up consistently.

Comment: Safari also has a reader view ([View > Show Reader](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-use-reader-view-in-safari/)) that simplifies the page ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8zF3.png)), but for some content that might actually make it _harder_ to consume.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, the option is turned on in Chrome on my Android 12 device. As mentioned on the link, view simplified pages is turned on in the accessibility chrome setting from the three dots of chrome in the upper right hand corner. However, I still see the standard pages with all the nice detailed layout. Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: It appears that option causes the pop-up to appear. And I think you have to tap on the pop-up each time you view a new page (in other words it's not persistent). As I mentioned, the pop-up doesn't seem to be consistent or I don't know what causes it to show up.